# PhpStorm / Symfony: Missing warning on non-existent service method call

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

If an non-existent method is called on a service, PHPStorm does not show warning.

ex: PHPStorm does not display "method not found"

```
 $this->get("vendor.service")->inexistentMethod();
```

ex: PHPStorm displays "method not found"

```
 /** @var VendorService $service  */
 $service = $this->get("vendor.service");
 $service->inexistentMethod();
```

Is it a bug or a configuration problem?

Env:

```
PhpStorm 2017.2
Build #PS-172.3317.83, built on July 18, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b5 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
Symfony Plugin Version: 0.14.149
```

Comment: This looks like bug report, not question.

Comment: @svgrafov. I've updated my question. Not sure if it is a bug or a configuration problem.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache ? Sometimes the autocomplete can be tricky

Comment: Not a Symfony user here. But it all may depend how `get()` is declared (what signature it has) and how Symfony plugins helps here. In your 2nd example you specifically telling that `$service` is an instance of `VendorService`. In case of `$this->get("vendor.service")->` it depends on what IDE knows about `get()` -- what `@return` it has. If it has something like `mixed` or alike (e.g. `stdClass` or other broad type) then it's kind of expected -- you cannot report missing/wrong method if type is "can be anything" -- will provide too many false positives.

Comment: I do not know how Symfony plugin solves it .. but for Laravel [IDE-helper exists](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) that generates [metadata file](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) ... which provides correct type hints (which does seem to work good enough considering that the return type declared via Advanced Metadata functionality seems to be gets merged with actual `@return` tag form PHPDoc).

Comment: @Florent Yes i cleared the cache. The problem still exists

Comment: @LazyOne the `get`method return an `object` type. And in previous version of PHPStorm / Symfony plugin the IDE displayed warnings if a service method call does not exist like in my first example.

Comment: @Tsounabe To [clarify](http://www.rearttheurban.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/9b10f32cb606fb6beec4884b4332689d.gif), it does not show a PHPStorm warning or there is no warning during runtime?

Comment: @Kaspars it does not show a PHPStorm warning

Answer (score 0):

install the symfony plugin for phpstorm